# How to include multiple columns from extra file in <p:dataTable>?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I use objects of different classes inside a `<p:dataTable>` and want to conditionally render multiple `<p:column>` for the different classes. I do not want to use `<p:columns>` as I would have to provide the data on what columns should be rendered mostly from a bean and I just want to do it in Facelets.

Actually I could do it just like shown below but for many different classes with different properties this would grow messy. I want all columns that are rendered on a certain condition included from another file.

```xml
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.object} var="object">
    <p:column rendered="#{myBean.classOfObject == 'Car'}" />
        #{object.yearOfConstruction}
    </p:column>
    <p:column rendered="#{myBean.classOfObject == 'Person'}">
        #{object.dateOfBirth}
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still open to suggestions to the following approach as well as new ones:

datatable.xhtml

```
<c:set var="isCar" value="#{param.type == 'Car'}" />
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.object} var="object">
    <ui:include src="car.xhtml"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

car.xhtml

```
<p:column rendered="#{isCar}" />
    #{object.yearOfConstruction}
</p:column>
<p:column rendered="#{isCar}" />
    #{object.color}
</p:column>
```

I am still not happy with the repeating `rendered`-condition.